# Composite Primary Key Constraint

Tags: sql, database-design, rdbms, composite-key

**Table Definitions:**

```
Student(StudentID, StudentName) PK StudentID

Faculty(FacultyID, FacultyName) PK FacultyID

Course(CourseID, CourseName) PK CourseID

Qualified(FacultyID, CourseID, DateQualified) PK FacultyID CourseID

Section(SectionNo,Semester, CourseID) PK SectionNo Semester CourseID

Registration(StudentID, SectionNo, Semester) PK StudentID SectionNo Semester
```

How can I link table Registration and Section?
StudentID in Registration as a foreign key references from StudentID in student table
But What can I do with SectionNo and Semester? I can add a constraint on a foreign key Section_Semester (SectionNo, Semester), but those two attributes are not unique in Section table. Add a constraint on primary key in Section table?

Thanks

Comment: Those aren't table definitions. CREATE TABLE statements are table definitions. (You can edit your question, and paste CREATE TABLE statements.) It's not clear from your description whether you're trying to create a foreign key in "registration" that references "section", or you're trying to create a foreign key in "section" that references "registration". Which is it?

Comment: `Section(SectionNo, ...` deviates from the convention of the other tables. Either `SectionNo` is itself a Primary Key (surrogate or natural), or it is just associated information with a key of `(Semester, CourseID)`,  or it is part of a composite key. Depending on which of the 3 is correct, your foreign key in `Registration` to `Section` must be adjusted to align with the Section primary key. As it stands, you will need to add `CourseID` to `Registration` and add it in the foreign key to Section.

Comment: In addition to seconding Stuart's and Mike's comments, the tables are not described, we do not know what you are trying to achieve, or which is the parent and which is the child in the two tables that you want to "link", or what purpose that serves.  If I take the title as the question, the answer is "yes, you can".  Each SQL and Non-SQL platform has different syntax, so you will have to look it up.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: Welcome back!

Comment: @Mike.  Thanks.  I am surprised anyone remembers me from four years ago!

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: [tag:database-design] is a small community.

Comment: To StuartLc, unfortunately I am not allowed to add or delet any attribute in any of those tables, that causes my frustration. To PerformanceDBA, I am trying to join section and registration table under the requirement which I listed in my question, restrict to the primary key which is indicated already in section and registration table, not allowed to add any other attributes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that your Section table has a primary key of (sectionNo,semester,courseID), and that there can thus be multiple records with the same sectionNo and semester? And then you want to connect Registration, which does not have a courseID, to this table? To the best of my knowledge you can't use a "references" clause because it will not link to a unique identifier. But that doesn't stop you from writing queries that join the two tables.

*Update*

Of course there are many possible queries depending on what it is you want to know. If, say, you want to know all the classes that student #17 has ever registered for, you could write:

```
select section.sectionno, section.semester, section.courseid
from registration
join section on section.sectionno=registration.sectionno 
  and section.semester=registration.semester 
where studentid=17
```

If you want all the courses for a given Registration record:

```
select coursed
from registration
join section on section.sectionno=registration.sectionno
  and section.semester=registration.semester
where registration.sectionno=@section
  and registration.semester=@semester
  and registration.studentid=@student
```

Now, hmm, writing that query this indicates to me that a student registers for all the courses making up a section and semester. Is this true? If there are multiple courses in a section and semester, does the student sign up for all of them at one time, or does he pick individual ones? If he picks, then it would seem that Registration needs to specify which course.

I don't know what "section" means here so I don't know how it relates.

Comment: Hey, Jay, you understood it very clearly. I cant write queries to join section table and registration table because of the reason you just metioned in your answer.

Comment: Why not? select section.sectionno, section.semester, section.courseid from registration join section on section.sectionno=registration.registrationno and section.semester=registration.semester where studentid=17 would give you all the courses that student 17 registered for, for example.

Comment: Hey Jay, could you write it down in SQL? I mean joining Section and Registration table? Besides, in Registration table there is no RegistrationNo as the primary key. It requires StudentID, SectionNo and Semester as the composite primary key.

Comment: @CaterinaChen Oh, sorry, I meant sectionno, not registrationno. Anyway, I've updated my answer to perhaps address your question.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your reply, I am sorry to say you didn't get me right. I was try to join Section table and Registration table. but because of the composite primary key in each table has three attribute and I can figure out how to reference it by using foreign key. In the end, I give up on those primary keys and write the code on my own.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a REFERENCES clause, you have to match a unique identifier on the target table with a corresponding field or set of fields on the source table. My point is, just because you can't create such a reference doesn't mean that you can't join the tables. The only thing that is lost is that the db engine won't validate the values in the FK. You write the join the same way either way. Maybe I'm still not understanding what your problem is.

Comment: Hey Jay, I believe you totoally understand what I want to achieve. At this point I am pretty sure the lecture of this course gave the question wrong or the lecture made a mistake on this question. This mistake was so annoying. Because for the knowledege we just have been taught, we were not expected to use the script you were using to join these two tables. But it is good to know new knowledge from what you've written any way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can have a complete registration tuple without CourseID. If the combination of SectionNo and Semester are not unique, then what has the student registered for? All of the specified sections for the semester? No, they register for a particular course (which meets at specified days at specified times at a specified location).

Of course, I have no idea what *Section* represents. But whatever it represents, it obviously doesn't have the granularity to narrow down exactly what the student has registered for. You have to include that.

Comment: Hey TommCatt, thanks. Section table here represents in which semester you can choose what courses I guess. regitration table here indicates which student choose which section (which course in which semester).

Comment: Yes. But there is no course information in the registration tuple. Or rather, it can refer to multiple courses as SectionNo and Semester do not refer to one course but to several. You must narrow that down somehow.